# Flutter timer.periodic - seconds x milliseconds

Tags: flutter

I was testing some code with Timer and I'm not undestanding a thing. I'm using a button to start two timers, one with 5 seconds and the other with 5000 milliseconds, and I thought they would stop at the same time, but the first one finished first, almost twice as fast.
Part of the code:

```
int timeLeftSec = 5;
int timeLeftMilSec = 5000;

onPressed: (){
   Timer.periodic(Duration seconds: 1), (timer){
      if(timeLeftSec > 0){
         timeLeftSec--;
      }else{
         timer.cancel();
      }
   }

   Timer.periodic(Duration milliseconds: 1), (timer){
      if(timeLeftMilSec > 0){
         timeLeftMilSec--;
      }else{
         timer.cancel();
      }
   }
}
´´´
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it's not working for you. I've written this little test and it works fine for me.

Do note that it takes 6 seconds for the 'seconds' timer to finish. I would imagine it'll take 5001 ms to finish the ms timer. But I doubt you would notice that.

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

void main() {

  test('timers', () async {
    int timeLeftSec = 5;
    int timeLeftMilSec = 5000;

    print('${DateTime.now()} Start');

    Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      if (timeLeftSec > 0) {
        timeLeftSec--;
        print('${DateTime.now()} seconds... $timeLeftSec');
      } else {
        print('${DateTime.now()} seconds done');
        timer.cancel();
      }
    });

    Timer.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: 1), (timer) {
      if (timeLeftMilSec > 0) {
        timeLeftMilSec--;
      } else {
        print('${DateTime.now()} ms done');
        timer.cancel();
      }
    });
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10));
  });
}
```

```
2021-11-10 10:12:25.438793 Start
2021-11-10 10:12:26.446849 seconds... 4
2021-11-10 10:12:27.446518 seconds... 3
2021-11-10 10:12:28.447383 seconds... 2
2021-11-10 10:12:29.447249 seconds... 1
2021-11-10 10:12:30.446504 seconds... 0
2021-11-10 10:12:30.449687 ms done
2021-11-10 10:12:31.447838 seconds done
```